# After installation of Office 2019 SharePOint 2019 removed

Tags: 2019

In a SharePoint 2019 Development Server I installed office 2019 using https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/deployoffice/office2019/deploy
 after installation, I found that SharePoint installation not found and I can not access the central administration.

after i tried to install again SharePoint 2019 binaries I[image] get the following message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per the notes under [Minimum software requirements for SharePoint Server 2019](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/install/hardware-and-software-requirements-2019#minimum-software-requirements-for-sharepoint-server-2019), it is not supported to install Office client on a SharePoint server.

> We don't support installing the Office 2019 client and SharePoint Server 2019 on the same computer.